# File upload not working with laravel $file on some machine

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload

In my Laravel project I created a page to upload the files and I use the $file of laravel it works fine for some system only but for some system  it shows an error as shown in image below.

[image: Error shows on file upload]

Function I am using to upload files in model

```
public function add_document_sub_cert($req)
    {
        $subcontractor_id = $req['subcontractor_id'];
        $reference_id = $req['reference_id'];


        $files = $req->file("uploaded_doc0");

        $i = 0;
        foreach($files as $file){
                $i++;
                $ext = $file->guessClientExtension();
                $name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
                $file_name_1 = str_replace(".".$ext,"",$name);


                $path  = $file->storeAs('subcontractor/','avc'.$i.'.jpg');

                if($path){
                    $document = new Document();
                    $document->doc_name = 'avc.jpg';
                    $document->module = 'subcontractor';
                    $document->reference_id = $reference_id;
                    $document->save();
                }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Shouldn't `($req)` be `(Request $req)` in your method parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Your error says that you didn't specify a filename. I see that your variable `$file_name_1` is never used. Haven't you forgotten to use it somewhere?

Without knowing how your class `Document` works, it's impossible to tell you exactly where is the bug.

Comment: No if thats a reason why working on other systems ?  and I use 'avc'.$i.'.jpg' as a file name ex avc1.jpg, avc2.jpg, avc3.jpg.....